# Why didn't Gary Powers use the cyanide in the coin?

Tags: character, bridge-of-spies

In Bridge of Spies, Gary Powers is given a coin with a cyanide needle hidden in it, to be used in case of capture.

But after his plane is shot down, we simply see him being in the custody of USSR soldiers. I want to know why he didn't use the cyanide. Did he get scared or did he not get enough time to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real Gary Powers discussed this in [an interview](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:42jQb5n3J9gJ:earth.google.com/gallery/kmz/francis_gary_powers.kmz%20&cd=9&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk). The easiest answer is that he wasn't under orders to use the curaré (note, not cyanide) needle to commit suicide if captured. The hidden needle was an optional tool and was presumed to be used in the event of torture rather than merely of capture. At the fateful moment, he did what most sensible POWs do and *just  decided not to kill himself.*

> "Apparently a great many people were under the impression that I had
>   been under orders to kill myself, come what may. But, as I had
>   attempted to make clear in the trial, I had no such orders. I was to
>   use the destruct device - which wouldn't have destroyed the plane,
>   only a portion of the equipment - if possible. Under the
>   circumstances, it had not been possible.
>
> "I could understand why, not having been in the cockpit with me, some
>   people might doubt my story. But when it came to the poison needle,
>   there shouldn't have been any doubt. Since carrying it was optional,
>   suicide was obviously optional too.
>
> "It bothered me that this criticism was apparently long-standing, and
>   that the CIA - although it would have been very easy to do so, without
>   in any way jeopardizing security - had made no attempt to set the
>   record straight by stating exactly what my instructions were. Instead
>   they had let this misapprehension, damning as it was, continue
>   undisputed."

The CIA also released the following statement at the subsequent Senate hearings

> "STATEMENT CONCERNING FRANCIS GARY POWERS."
>
> **'The pilots...were instructed .... to be cooperative with their
>   captors within limitations, to use their own judgement of what they
>   should attempt to withhold, and not to subject themselves to strenuous
>   hostile interrogation.** It has been established that Mr. Powers had
>   been briefed in accordance with this policy and so understood his
>   guidance.
>
> '**In regard to the poison needle....it should be emphasized that this
>   was intended for use primarily if the pilot were subjected to torture
>   or other circumstances which in his discretion warranted the taking of
>   his own life. There were no instructions that he should commit suicide
>   and no expectation that he would do so except in those situations just
>   described, and I emphasize that even taking the needle with him in the
>   plane was not mandary; it was his option.'**

Interestingly, [this statement](http://www.militarycorruption.com/HOF-Powers.htm) from his commanding officer Gen. Arch Hamblen seems to conflict with the accepted version of events:

> ... Powers carried with him
>   cyanide, in a pen, which he was supposed to take in case he was shot
>   down on the mission. The U-2 was built to fly higher - 65,000 to
>   70,000 feet - than any Soviet missile could reach. But his plane was
>   hit and he parachuted out of the stricken aircraft. He could not reach
>   the cyanide instrument - anyway, it was destroyed by the impact of the
>   missile. The spy pilot was captured and put in prison.